# How do I hide that setting-box on a click anywhere outside of the element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, popup

[image]

> I would like to know whether this is the correct way of close settings when clicked anywhere on the
> page.
>
> > it works when I just clicking on the icon gear .

```
// Toggle Span Class On Icon
let toogleBox = document.querySelector(".toggle-setting .fa-gear").onclick = function () {
// toggle class fa-spin for Rotation on self
this.classList.toggle('open');
```

// Toggle class Open On Main Setting Box
document.querySelector(".setting-box").classList.toggle('open');
};

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on your purpose. You have to decide from user's point of view. As I think it is not necessary: user should have an opportunity to interact with other elements on the his/her page.

Comment: all i want when i open this setting box , and I press any place on the page have to close!

Comment: It is very simple. Just add the invisible block over your page and place the click callback on it.